# PHP Mysql database MVC structure advice needed

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, database-design

I am trying to figure out the best way to have a page dynamically know which data to output.

I have a index.php that I want to be able to pass some $_GET variables into it and then based on that know what to display. Aside from the content being different the type of the content is also different I have products and other types of pages like blog posts etc. The products are stored in different tables then the other pages. and also have a slightly different table structure as well.

currently I have the following tables.

Subjects, Pages and Categories.

```
Table = Subjects
id | menu_name | menu_number | category | menu_position | active

Table = Pages
id | subject_id | category_id | page_name

Table = Categories
id | category
```

These are the main tables that outline the main structure of the site. I then have secondary tables that contain the actual data for the pages.

posts, post_details, post_pypes and
products, product_details, product_types and product_specs.

What I want to active is that a variable will be send along in the query string and based on this the application will know what information to display .

My question is how can I make a table that will catalog all entries (posts and products) with a unique id and that will be the only variable needed to for my application to determine how to proceed. i.e. query the table int he database that is holding that unique id and tell the application its a "product" and the product id is X and to continue querying the needed tables for the info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're gonna vote it down at least provide some input.

Comment: Im not asking for anybody to do any work for me, I want advice on how to go about building a table that can catalog all other entries in the db, just looking for some pointing in the right direction.

Comment: isn't that why this site is here to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend looking into a secure, structured environment like CodeIgniter to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to describe above.  The scope of that question is really broad which likely indicates that you would profit from a prebuilt framework of some kind.